# Getting "GET /user HTTP/1.1" 401 28 in django development server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, jwt, http-status-code-401

When I login in my reactjs i get jwt token but at backend didn't recieve the token is empty
it execute this part of code and  after printing token  `token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')` `None` is printed why I am not getting the cooking in backend. since i got cookies in my browser after i login
cookies:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NywiZXhwIjoxNjkzMjQ3NDA3LCJpYXQiOjE2OTMyNDM4MDd9.SPecH4BsNh76EjTHMoSDzWfaT8dt8KhnfNYKx8qQ0OU

Django code

```
        print(token)
        if not token:
            print("dint get token")
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')
```

```
class UserView(APIView):
    # permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
        print(token)
        if not token:
            print("dint get token")
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')

        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])

        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
           
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')

        user = User.objects.filter(id=payload['id']).first()
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)

        return Response(serializer.data)`
```

reactjs code

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
const HomePage = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        (
            async () => {
                const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user', {
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    credentials: 'include',
                });

                if (response.ok) {
                    const content = await response.json();
                    setName(content.name);
                    console.log(name);
                    const cookies = document.cookie;
                    const token = cookies.split(';')[0].split('=')[1];
                    const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
                    console.log(decodedToken);
                } else {
                    console.log('Error fetching user data');
                }

            }
        )();
    }, [fetch]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hi {name}</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HomePage;`
```

django backend didn't receive the cookies